# How to refactor a request HTTPAdapter for use with aiohttp?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am currently migrating my application to be completely async.  Naturally, I am rewriting my usage of `requests` library to use `aiohttp` which is an async http client. I have a required `HTTPAdapter` I have to use but I can't find a way to create adapters in the aiohttp library.  Does this functionality exist?

My HTTPAdapter if it makes a difference:

```
CIPHERS = ':'.join([
    'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256', 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256', 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384',
    'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384', 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305', 'ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305',
    'DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256', 'DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384', 'DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305', 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256',
    'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256', 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA', 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA', 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384',
    'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384', 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA', 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA', 'DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256',
    'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256', 'AES128-GCM-SHA256', 'AES256-GCM-SHA384', 'AES128-SHA256', 'AES256-SHA256', 'AES128-SHA',
    'AES256-SHA', 'DES-CBC3-SHA'
])


class TlsAdapter(HTTPAdapter):

    def __init__(self, ssl_options=0, **kwargs):
        self.ssl_options = ssl_options
        super(TlsAdapter, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def init_poolmanager(self, *pool_args, **pool_kwargs):
        ctx = ssl_.create_urllib3_context(ciphers=CIPHERS, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, options=self.ssl_options)
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(*pool_args,
                                       ssl_context=ctx,
                                       **pool_kwargs)
```

Then implemented as

```
adapter = TlsAdapter(ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1)
session.mount("https://", adapter)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [TCPConnector](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/latest/client_reference.html?highlight=TCPConnector#tcpconnector) to pass a custom [SSL context](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.create_default_context) so something like this should work:

```
import asyncio
import ssl

import aiohttp

URL = "https://stackoverflow.com"
CIPHERS = [
    ...
]


async def main():
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context()

    ctx.options |= (ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1)
    ctx.set_ciphers(":".join(CIPHERS))
    ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED

    conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=ctx)

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn) as client:
        async with client.get(URL) as r:
            print(r.status)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: After implementing this, it didn't seem to have the same effect as it did in the requests library. (Use case - accessing an API which requires a specific SSL handshake)  Getting the same error with/without it.

Comment: Can you show the error? You can try to use the `ssl_.create_urllib3_context` to create the context and see if that will help

Comment: If I swap to `ssl_.create_urllib3_context()` I have to use `ssl.CERT_NONE`  or else I get this error `certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate`  .  but then I get the same error as I do normally.

The error I am speaking about is a cloudflare 1020 error (no stacktrace or anything, it just means you are blocked by from accessing the endpoint via cloudflare) which is why I initially implemented the `TlsAdapter` for requests.

Comment: I believe the CF 1020 error means access denied so I don’t think it’s related to the SSL options in use. A few things to consider: `1.` Your IP is not allowed/blocked by the CF firewall, `2.` CF doesn’t like the user agent you send in the headers. If you own the API service, you should be able to track which CF firewall rule is blocking your requests.